# extracting result txt file to specific folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, omnet++

I have a simulation and I am assigning 2 processes to different cores.Every simulation extracts an output file at the end of simulation.The thing is that I want to do, at the end of the simulation, result file should be extracted to specific folder.If the run number is 0 result file should be result0.txt , if it is 1 result1.txt (result file is created by a class while simulating ). I am new in Linux so I don't know bash script.I just try to learn.How can I do this is there any way to do that?

```
#!/bin/bash
# My first script

count=0
echo -n "Enter a number of simulation > "
read number
echo "Please enter the algorithm type > "
echo -n "0 for NNA  1 for SPA   2 for EEEA > "

while read type; do
    case $type in
        0 ) while [ $count -lt $number ]; do
            cd /home/cea/Desktop/simulation/wsnfuture
        taskset -c $((count % 4)) ./wsnfuture -u Cmdenv omnetpp.ini > wsn1 
            count=$((count + 1))
        done 
        ;;
        1 ) while [ $count -lt $number ]; do
            cd /home/cea/Desktop/simulation/wsnfuture1
        taskset -c $((count % 4)) ./wsnfuture -u Cmdenv omnetpp.ini > wsn1 
            count=$((count + 1))
        done 
        ;;
        2 ) while [ $count -lt $number ]; do
            cd /home/cea/Desktop/simulation/wsnfuture2
        taskset -c $((count % 4)) ./wsnfuture -u Cmdenv omnetpp.ini > wsn1 
            count=$((count + 1))
        done 
        ;;
        * ) echo "You did not enter a number"
        echo "between 0 and 2."
        echo "Please enter the algorithm type > "
        echo "0 for NNA  1 for SPA   2 for EEEA > "
    esac
done
```

wsn1 just shows the running number and elapsed time of the simulation.

Comment: Consider editing the code to make it one piece

Comment: Which files here are the "output files" in question? Do the output folders already exist? If so, where? If not, where do they need to be created? How are the contents you are looking to extract actually extracted from the output files?

Comment: At the end of the simulation, vaues.txt, sent.txt and received.txt files are created in the wsnfuture folder.wsnfuture includes one type of algorithm and wsnfuture2 includes another algorithm type. I am getting simulation number and algorithm type from user.If 0 is the type and 5 is the number of simulation, I need to collect this simulation ".txt " results into another folder , not in the wsnfuture. I mean if the count =0, I want to create a folder which is named type0 and this folder should contain the  " .txt"  file with respect to count number vaules0.txt, sent0.txt.

Comment: Or in the count0,count1.... in the type0 folder.Is it possible?